# Using class variable to cache DB data, will this be shared among web app's users?

Tags: java, jsp, scope

I know this is a fundamental question on Java's static variables, but I would like an official answer, maybe a pointer to the right documentation.

I am using a static variable to cache the results from the database. Question is, will these results be shared among all users of the web application?

Here's my code:

```
private static TreeMap<String,String> cachedOwners = null;
public static TreeMap<String,String> fetchOwners( ) 
        throws Exception
{
    if ( Owners.cachedOwners != null )
    {
        return Owners.cachedOwners;
    }

    DBHandler db = DBHandler.getInstance( );
    Owners.cachedOwners = db.fetchCAROwners( );
    return Owners.cachedOwners;
}
```

Now, based on my tests, caching works and the static variable "cachedOwners" is shared among all users of the application.

How come this happens? I thought a static variable is only tied to a user's session.

Comment: If you want an object to be tied up to a session, then use sessions setattribute.

Comment: *"I thought a static variable is only tied to a user's session."* Can you name a web programming language where this was *actually* the case? That language would have been broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!

There is not only *one* official documentation because there are two sides together

1. classloader inheritation
2. java-webserver classloading order

Static means the same address in the classloader-inheritation, so, if you ever have two webapplications using the same inherted "classloader".

i.e. if you have an singeton.jar with an

```
static int org.me.Test.born=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

an the singleton.jar is located in

- tomcat/lib,
- tomcat/webapps/webapp1/WEB-INF/libs/
- and tomcat/webapps/webapp2/WEB-INF/libs/

only the "tomcat/lib" will be define the born-field because the /lib-classloader will be load first.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables do not hold any state of a user's session.
They are solely methods that are not bound to the lifetime of the object.
This means that you can access these static variables from everywhere in your code.
That comes with some drawbacks, for example it is hard to test static methods, because the state can survice multiple tests.
I discourage you from using static Variables for Caches!

Please check this Oracle Documentation about the difference of static and class members:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html